What does "answer exactly" mean?
I got a question on a math test and am confused as to why my answer would be incorrect. This is the question:
Solve for $x$, answer exactly with both answers and show your calculations:
$x^2-3=17$
I answered:
$$\begin{align}
x^2-3=17 \\
x^2=20 \\\
x=±\sqrt{20} \\\
x=±\sqrt{5*4} \\\
x=±\sqrt{5}*\sqrt{4} \\\
x=2*±\sqrt{5} \\\
\end{align}$$
Which is what I would call the most exact form. But this got marked as wrong with the right answer being $±\sqrt{20}$, an answer I would say is less "exact". My teacher came up with the argument that the question did not say the answer in the simplest radical form, which is illogical since that is often the preferred form if not stated otherwise.
Am I in the wrong here?

I would agree with you that there is no reason to prefer $\sqrt {20}$ to $2\sqrt {5}$.  That said, I think the way you wrote your answer is confusing....better to write $\pm 2\sqrt 5$.

Should add:  as a general matter, it's probably a good idea to conform to the standards set by your instructor, at least where possible.  Perhaps ask the instructor to clarify just what those standards are, however.

The last line can take my sleep away realising that it's a valid notation

What was the exact wording of the problem? If it was to find the solutions to the equation (and nothing else), then your answer is correct. Therefore your teacher is in the wrong since the correctness of the answer is in no way influenced by its presentation.

"My teacher came up with the argument that the question did not say the answer in the simplest radical form, which is illogical since that is often the preferred form if not stated otherwise." I agree with you: it doesn't make sense to me why your teacher is discouraging you to simplify surds. Usually on tests, if the question does not specify which form the answer must be in, then so long as the answer is correct, then the mark must be awarded.

When I first read it, it looked like you were writing $2\pm\sqrt{5}$. That is a strange notation. He shouldn't have taken any points, though. And yes, $2\sqrt{5}$ is just as exact as $\sqrt{20}$.

Welcome to Stack Exchange! I can see both sides of the debate. Ultimately there isn’t a preferred way to present the solution unless stated, in fact simplifying surds is usually better. However, your answer could perhaps be written in a more clear manner, as it’s easy to misread your solution. It would be far better to write $ \pm 2 \sqrt{5}$, as there there is no chance of misreading your solution.
